# IOS Version only for Ipads

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

I have AppA v.1.0 that supports iPhones and iPads. I have a new update for it AppA v.2.0, for which the iPad design is ready but the iPhone's design is not. I need to launch it asap only for iPads. I don't want to create a separate application.

So what I want is to provide AppA v.1.0 for mobiles and AppA v.2.0 for iPads.

Comment: When you say, "version" do you mean you have entirely different applications for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: yes i have aversion for poth iphones and ipads and i wan't to add new version for ipads and the old only must be visible for iphones only

Comment: no you can't... even if you have update for iPad only, you will upload the binary as universal...

Comment: also any reason to do such thing?

Comment: As I said in a comment to one of the answers, this question has been updated because of low quality while there were already some responses. This questions should be re-asked.

Comment: In short, you can't. A Universal app can never be downgraded to support just the iPhone or just the iPad. It must always be a Universal app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you cannot do that.

If you remove iPhone support you will most likely get a rejection of your binary

> This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by
>   the previous app version. Your app update must continue to support all
>   devices previously supported. You declare supported devices in Xcode
>   with the Targeted Device Family build setting. Refer to QA1623 for
>   additional
>   information:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html

Secondly if somehow you could do it then if you have AppA v1.0 and release AppA v2.0 then 1.0 is not available anymore to anyone on App Store and v2.0 becomes the released version. What that means for your NEW iPhone users is that if they search for your app name on their device they will see no search results returned. On iPad it will be shown. Again your two options are

- Make a universal app and support both iPhone and iPad. If you got most of the code working for iPad then making it work for iPhone isn't that big leap.
- Make a new app for iPad only.

Comment: I agree the question is confusing but there are two edits!! Both question and answer have evolved. I suggest the question be removed so that it is asked again correctly.

Comment: @SamB Suggestion - since the question has been updated, edit your answer so it only addresses the current version of the question. Keeping the old part of the answer around makes it hard to read.